# Calling setState from setTimeout causes unexpected text field cursor jump

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, setstate

After adding a few keystrokes to the input field in this [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/edzy8kp7/), then placing the caret somewhere in the text and adding another keystroke, the caret will jump to the end of the input field rather than preserving its position. This does not happen when the `setState` call is not within `setTimeout`. Why is the asynchronous `setState` causing these issues? Is there a way to get the desired behavior while still calling `setState` asynchronously?

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ""};
    this.handleState = this.handleState.bind(this);
  }

  handleState(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({value: value});
    }, 10);
  }

  render() {
    return <input
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleState} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: `setState` is already asynchronous. Why do you need it in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: Get rid of the `setTimeout`, there is no need to do that, and it obviously causes problems.

Comment: I'm trying to gain a better understanding of the mechanisms at play here. The behavior surprised me, especially because `setState` is already asynchronous.